# EmguCV Mat object is always null in .NET MAUI Android

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, emgucv, maui

I want to capture camera frames by using Emgu.CV in .NET MAUI and I have Emgu.CV runtime for MAUI Android. I can access the camera but I couldn't transfer the feed to Mat object. It's always null. The same code is working on Windows Forms and WPF but on MAUI it's not. Also `_capture.ImageGrabbed += _capture_ImageGrabbed;` doesn't trigger `_capture_ImageGrabbed` event.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private VideoCapture _capture = null;
    //private bool _captureInProgress;
    private Mat _frame;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
        CvInvokeAndroid.Init();
        _capture = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCapture.API.Android);
        _capture.ImageGrabbed += _capture_ImageGrabbed;
        _frame = new Mat();
    }

    private void captureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture.Start();        
    }

    private void _capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);
    }

    private void ManuelFrame_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _capture.Retrieve(_frame, 0);
        if (_frame.IsEmpty)
        {
            statusLabel.Text = "frame is null";
        }
        else statusLabel.Text = "frame is not null";
    }
}
```

**Images**

[image: debug]

[image: android emulator]

[image: different]

As you can see, After Retrieve method, Mat object shouldn't be null.

I can access the camera with capture but I can't transfer the capture to _frame object. I tried to change Android API to 33 (Android 13) it didn't work. I put a manuel event for retrieving frame it also didn't work. What can I do?

***UPDATE***

I implemented the code which is released for MAUI from EmguCV Github [page](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/blob/df7e1de894808f754ce3600a4c3a54055305cb24/Emgu.CV.Platform/Maui/UI/ProcessAndRenderPage.cs).
However, the ImageGrabbed event is never triggered and Mat objects are still empty.

**GitHub Implementation**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private VideoCapture _capture = null;
    //private bool _captureInProgress;
    private Mat _mat;
    private Mat _renderMat;
    private string _defaultButtonText = "Start Camera";
    protected string _StopCameraButtonText = "Stop Camera";
    private string _deaultImage;
    ButtonTextImagePage buttonPage = new ButtonTextImagePage();

    private IProcessAndRenderModel _model;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false;
        CvInvokeAndroid.Init();
        InitVideoCapture();
    }

    private void _capture_ImageGrabbed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mat == null)
            _mat = new Mat();
        _capture.Retrieve(_mat);

        if (_renderMat == null)
            _renderMat = new Mat();

        _mat.CopyTo(_renderMat);
    }

    protected virtual async void captureButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = buttonPage.GetButton();

        if(captureButton.Text.Equals(_StopCameraButtonText))
        {
#if __ANDROID__ && __USE_ANDROID_CAMERA2__
                StopCapture();
                //AndroidImageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
#else
            _capture.Stop();
            _capture.Dispose();
            _capture = null;
#endif
            captureButton.Text = _defaultButtonText;
            return;
        }

        Mat[] images;
        if(_deaultImage == null)
        {
            images = new Mat[0];
        }
        else
        {
            images = await buttonPage.LoadImages(new string[] { _deaultImage });

            if (images == null || (images.Length > 0 && images[0] == null)) return;
        }

        if(images.Length == 0)
        {
#if __ANDROID__ && __USE_ANDROID_CAMERA2__
               
                StartCapture(async delegate (Object captureSender, Mat m)
                {
                    //Skip the frame if busy, 
                    //Otherwise too many frames arriving and will eventually saturated the memory.
                    if (!_isBusy)
                    {
                        _isBusy = true;
                        try
                        {
                            String message = String.Empty;
                            await Task.Run(() => 
                            {
                                if (_renderMat == null)
                                    _renderMat = new Mat();
                                using (InputArray iaImage = m.GetInputArray())
                                {
                                    iaImage.CopyTo(_renderMat);
                                }
                                message = _model.ProcessAndRender(m, _renderMat);
                            });
                            SetImage(_renderMat);
                            SetMessage(message);

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            _isBusy = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
#else
            //Handle video
            if (_capture == null)
            {
                InitVideoCapture();
            }

            if (_capture != null)
                _capture.Start();
#endif
            captureButton.Text = _StopCameraButtonText;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_renderMat == null) _renderMat = new Mat();
            images[0].CopyTo(_renderMat);
        }

    }

    private void InitVideoCapture()
    {
        var openCVConfigDict = CvInvoke.ConfigDict;
        bool haveVideoio = (openCVConfigDict["HAVE_OPENCV_VIDEOIO"] != 0);
        if (haveVideoio && Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
        {
#if __ANDROID__ && __USE_ANDROID_CAMERA2__
                return true;
#else
            if (CvInvoke.Backends.Length > 0)
            {
                if (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
                {
                    _capture = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCapture.API.Android);
                }
                else
                {
                    _capture = new VideoCapture();
                }
                if (_capture.IsOpened)
                {
                    _capture.ImageGrabbed += _capture_ImageGrabbed;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    _capture.Dispose();
                    _capture = null;
                }
            }
#endif
        }
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Android Emulator is not working correctly with EmguCV on .NET MAUI. I deployed the application my physical device and it worked. However, OpenCV's video capture is broken for android. I opened the camera but all time image is in black-gray format. If you working with real-time camera you can make two things. Install android studio and change the camera source with your webcam or directly build on your physical device.